# Create vertical Kendo Sparkline?

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

I am using Telerik's [Kendo UI](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui) for some charts and graphs. I created a "bullet" type sparkline, but it lies horizontally by default. Is there any way to rotate it or force it to stand vertically?

The CSS3 rotate property works well for modern browsers, but I need a way to support IE 8.

I tried using the -ms-filter: matrix rotation commonly used to rotate divs in IE 8, but it doesn't seem to play well with the Kendo Sparkline (sparkline doesn't rotate at all).

Comment: You want the whole charts to render vertically with horizontal bars?
Could you use RadHtml BarChart instead of the sparkline ones?

Comment: @AndrewWalters I'm using the "bullet" type sparkline (http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sparklines/index - under Temperature Control), so the RadHtml BarChart wouldn't work.

Comment: The bullet type has vertical bars though, is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: I could use it, but since the bullet sparkline already presents data in the way I want to, I was looking for a quick fix in case I just missed it.